# Java JPA - Table per class inheritance - Id collision

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have one Parent class with ID field, and two Child classes. I have applied TABLE PER CLASS inheritance.
Some Rows in these two tables have the same identifiers. (The same Id)

When findAll() of the JpaRepository is called I have org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException

What I can to do to resolve the conflict? I can not to change IDs in these tables, because they have a lot of dependencies and foreign key constraints.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Parent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "content_id_generator",
        table = "generic_sequences",
        pkColumnName = "sequence_name",
        valueColumnName = "sequence_value",
        pkColumnValue= "content_seq",
        allocationSize = 20)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "content_id_generator")
@Column(updatable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 250, nullable = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 250)
private String title;

...
```

**There are tho child classes Child1 and Child2 extends Parent.**

**There is another inheritance that dependent from Content.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "text_id_changed")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class DependentCalss implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(updatable = false)
private Long id;

...
```

**DependentCalss has two child classes DependentCalssChild1 and DependentCalssChild2.**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DependentCalssChild1")
public class DependentCalssChild1 extends DependentCalss {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "child_1_id")
private Child1 child1;
...
```

AND

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DependentCalssChild2")
public class DependentCalssChild2 extends DependentCalss {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "child_2_id")
private Child2 child2;
...
```

And jpaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface DependentCalssRepository extends JpaRepository<DependentCalss, Long> {
}
```

When I call **findAll()** of DependentCalssRepository I catch **org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException** that field can not be set etc.

It happens when Child1 and Child2 have the same ID in separate tables.
What can I do to resolve it? I can not change id in tables because of great number dependencies and constraints. Thanks!

Comment: could you please provide the code of parent class?

Comment: updated. Thanks!